# Proving that a map is birational

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Prove that, given an algebraic plane curve $X$, the map $f: \mathbb{A}^1 \to X$ defined as $f(t) = (t^2, t^3)$ and the map $f: \mathbb{A}^1 \to X$ defined as $g(t) = (t^2 - 1, t(t^2 -1))$ are birational.

**My attempt** For the first one I wrote $x= t^2$ and $y=t^3$ and then $\frac{y}{x}= t$. I think I can’t go on from here, I don’t even know if expressing $t$ in terms of only $x$ and $y$ is helpful.

Comment: Please define the concept of "birationality".

Comment: A rational map is birational if it has an inverse rational map.

Comment: "I can't express $t$ in terms of only $x$ and $y$." But didn't you already do that when you wrote $t=\frac{y}{x}$?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that’s definitely what I did. What I meant instead is that I don’t know if expressing $t$ like that is going to be helpful to find the inverse.

Comment: Hint: you already found the inverse.

Comment: Ok, so is it $f^{-1}(x,y) = y/x$?

Comment: If that is the case, $f^{-1} = g^{-1}$, right?